# python-pyramid app memory is not releasing at all

Tags: python, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy, pyramid

How to solve this memory leak?

What measures should I take to cleanup old session objects?
Isn't `session.close()` is sufficient?

or

Is it something to do with pyramid?

```
Sqlalchmey setup:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_db(request):
    maker = request.registry.dbmaker
    session = maker()

    @profile
    def cleanup(request):
        _session = request.db
        if request.exception is not None:
            _session.rollback()
        else:
            _session.commit()
        _session.close()
        # del _session     # No memory released

    request.add_finished_callback(cleanup)
    return session

def main(global_config, **settings):
    :
    :
    config.registry.dbmaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    config.add_request_method(get_db, name='db', reify=True)
    :
    :
```

Pyramid app request handler is like

```
@view_config(route_name='list_employees', renderer='json')
def employees(request):
   session = request.db
   office = session.query(Office).get(1)
   employees = [x.name for x in office.employees]
   return employees
```

Now the problem is, In every request to list_employees the memory is growing.
the size of increase in memory is almost equal to size of `office.employees.`

Debug:

```
request 1 starts with memory utilization = 10MB
request 1 ends with memory utilization = 18MB

request 2 starts with memory utilization = 18MB
request 2 ends with memory utilization = 26MB        

request 3 starts with memory utilization = 26MB
request 3 ends with memory utilization = 34MB        
                 :
                 :
           Grows eventually

employees = [x.name for x in office.employees]
This is the line where about 8-10MB memory utilized
```

To debug, I added **__del__** method in Employ and Office models, looks like they are deleting.

Also tried `session.expunge(office)`, `del office` and `gc.collect()`

I am debugging memory consumption using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler
Also I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transaction is other requests.

Not using debug pyramid toolbar.

**EDIT** : Found memory increase at this line (employees = [x.name for x in office.employees]) shows zero after 6-7 requests. But query was returning same number of rows.

**EDIT** : Added standalone app https://github.com/Narengowda/pyramid_sqlalchemy_app

**EDIT**:  ITS NOT RELATED TO SQLALCHEMY AT ALL(my bad).
Wrote a simple view function which doesn't have any sqlalchmey queries.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000
        self.y = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000
        self.z = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000
        self.i = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000
        self.v = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000
        self.o = 'sdfklhasdjkfhasklsdkjflksdfksd' *1000


@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='json')
def my_view(request):
    return test(request)

@profile
def test(request):
    count = request.GET.get('count')
    l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
    print l[0]
    return {}
```

I am able to see this, below are the logs of requests

### REQUEST: 1

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23     37.3 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25     37.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    112.4 MiB     75.1 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    112.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    112.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

### REQUEST: 2

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25    111.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    187.3 MiB     75.6 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    187.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    187.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

### REQUEST: 3

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23    184.3 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25    184.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    259.7 MiB     75.4 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    259.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    259.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

### REQUEST: 4

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23    255.1 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25    255.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    330.4 MiB     75.3 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    330.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    330.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

### REQUEST: 5

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23    328.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25    328.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    330.5 MiB      2.3 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

### REQUEST: 6

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

---

```
23    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
24                             def test(request):
25    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       count = request.GET.get('count')
26    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       l = [Test() for i in range(int(count))]
27    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       print l[0]
28    330.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return {}
```

I have tried many times with different count query param, saw increase in memory utilization stops after exactly 5 requests(magic).

Also I tried to print all the objects and compared there addresses
what I observed is take a look at logs of request 4 and 5.
Looks like GC happened, hence memory reduced from 330.4 Mi to 328.2 MiB
But you wont see 75.3 MiB Memory utilization to create new objects(line 26) but you can see just 2.3 MiB increase.
Later I verified address of the objects created in last two requests, found 80% address of the objects from last two requests are same

### REQUEST: 4 objects addresses

```
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a042d0>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04310>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04350>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04390>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a043d0>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04410>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04450>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04490>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a044d0>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04510>
```

### REQUEST: 5 objects addresses

```
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04390>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a043d0>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04410>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04450>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04490>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a044d0>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04290>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04550>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a04590>
<pyramid_sqa.views.Test object at 0x3a045d0>
```

so new objects are created and python is reusing memory(reusing object!!?)

Is it OK if my server memory shoots up memory like this?

Comment: first of all, you might want to use `pyramid_tm` for the transaction handling and xact middleware.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is it mandatory?
http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/11-sqlalchemy/

Comment: Nope, only it thinks the correct flow for you already.

Comment: did you try to use gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK | gc.DEBUG_STATS)? maybe this will output anything interesting? should highlight any non collectables

Answer (score 3):

Python does its own memory management for Python objects, and even when the CPython GC frees a Python object, it still will not release the memory to the operating system (as malloc()/free() might do). When the GC frees a Python object, the memory can then be used for new Python objects. This is the effect you see when the memory consumption does not increase for request number 6. After number 5, the GC freed the deleted objects and the new object in request number 6 could use the freed memory.

So you do not have a memory leak, you just discovered how CPython memory management works. The memory consumption does not grow without bounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how python works, and how python does its memory management, so technically speaking, this is not a problem.

Now, I could write you a boring paragraph, going into more detail about why that is, but it is a too large of a topic, and you definately do not want to mess with memory management. However, I did find a website that sums it all up nicely, in an easy to understand format: [here it is](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm)

With that said, the only thing you could try, which may work, but possibly, may also not work, is to use the python [Garbage Collector Interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html), and *force* it to free unused memory, like this:

```
gc.collect()
```

However, not the emphasis on '*force*', as you should generally not mess with the Python GC, because it knows how to do its job, and in most cases, does it well, but if its your only option, it may be worth a shot.

Comment: Calling `gc.collect()` is not considered messing with memory management at all. Feel free to run it, but it will not help. See my answer for why.

Comment: @Anton I know that the chances are it will not work, because I do know how Python's memory management works, however, it may be worth giving it a shot, as it is pretty much, the only option. I appreciate your comment though.